# Query parsing error like clause

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql

What is the correct syntax for a query that retrieves all Accounts that have __Civil_ in the Name?

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE (Name LIKE '%_Civil_%')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape the _ because the _ is a wildcard that matches exactly one character.

The query would look like:

[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%\_Card\_%']

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query the underscores, then you have to escape them using `\`. Like in:

```
...WHERE Name LIKE '\_\_Civil\_'
```

If you want to use them as wildcards for matching any character, then your query should work, although you don't need the `(` and `)` for it to work.

Please refer to the documentation of the WHERE condition, on the **Comparison Operators** section: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm

Comment: The irony of me not escaping my own escape slashes in the answer and they didn't show up hahahah